# Split a long String in c# without breaking a words

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0, c#-5.0

i want to break a long String in c# without breaking a words
Example: S AAA BBBBBBB CC DDDDDD V        Breaking Character on 7 Count

```
S AAA 
BBBBBBB
CC 
DDDDDD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `substring` function c#

This link might helpful to you.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

```
count=0;
for(int i=0;i<str.Length;i++)
{
 if(str.Length%7==0)
 input.Substring(count, 7);
 count++;
}
```

Hope you can aply further logic about it.